# Column layout used for form, but not for display of entries

Tags: forms, devdemon

Forms: 3.5.3

ExpressionEngine: 2.11.1

I have a fairly long form that has where a good portion of the fields are setup in 2 columns - that layout is used when viewing/entering data into the form itself. But when I output submissions to the form using the {exp:forms:entries} tag, the output is all in a single column (the fields are also not in the same order as they are when editing/viewing the form itself, but that's a separate issue).

Is there any way to make the output of the {exp:forms:entries} use the same layout as the {exp:forms:form} tag?

Edit: just occurred to me, is it possible that using columns is the cause of the entries tag not displaying fields in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does DevDemon no longer support this software? This is the method the devdemon.com website recommends on their website for obtaining support, since their support forum is now read-only - but for more than a month, there's been no response to this & another Forms-related question I've posted.

Anyway, I ended up cobbling together a workaround, requiring a number of add-ons:

Stash - https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash
String Explode Tag - https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/string-explode-tag
Find and Replace Plus
VMG Nested

StackExchange won't allow posting the last 2 links... but both should be easy enough to find through google/devot-ee. Here's the code:

```
{exp:query sql="select field_id, title as field_title, description, field_type, field_settings, field_order from exp_forms_fields WHERE (form_id = '9' AND parent_id = '' AND field_type != 'pagebreak' AND field_type != 'hidden_field' AND field_id != '350' ) ORDER BY field_order"}
    {if field_type == "html"}
        {exp:replace_plus find=";s|:QUOTE:" replace="" multiple="yes"}{exp:strexplode delimiter=":" string='{field_settings}' index="6"}{/exp:replace_plus}
    {if:elseif field_type == "columns_2"}
        <p>
            <!-- field_title: {field_title} -->
            {if "{field_title}" != "2 Columns"}<span class="column-title"><strong>{field_title}</strong></span><br />{/if}
            {!-- QUERY TO GET "CHILD" FIELDS --}
            {exp:vmg_nested:query prefix="column" sql="select field_id, title as field_title, field_type, field_settings from exp_forms_fields WHERE (form_id = '9' AND parent_id = '{field_id}') ORDER BY field_order" parse="inward"}
                <strong>{column:field_title}:</strong> 

                {!-- QUERY TO GET CHILD FIELD DATA --}
                {embed="snippets/child-field-data" field_id="{column:field_id}" segment_4="{segment_4}" fentry_query="{exp:stash:get name='fentry_query'}"}
                {!-- /QUERY TO GET CHILD FIELD DATA --}

            {/exp:vmg_nested:query}
            {!-- /QUERY TO GET "CHILD" FIELDS --}
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    {if:elseif field_type == "file_upload"}
        <p><strong>{field_title}: </strong><br />
        {if "{description}" != ""}<br /><small><em>{description}</em></small><br />{/if}
        {!-- QUERY TO GET FIELD DATA --}
            {exp:vmg_nested:query prefix="data_reg" sql="select fid_{field_id} from exp_forms_entries WHERE (form_id = '9' AND fid_371 = '{segment_4}' AND fid_{field_id} !='') LIMIT 1"}
                {if "{data_reg:fid_{field_id}}" != ""}
                    <a href="/library/form-uploads/{data_reg:fid_{field_id}}"><img style="max-width: 70%; height: auto;" src="/scripts/thumbgen/thumbgen.php?src=/library/form-uploads/{data_reg:fid_{field_id}}&w=800" /></a>
                    <br />
                {/if}
                <em>{data_reg:fid_{field_id}}</em>
            {/exp:vmg_nested:query}
        {!-- /QUERY TO GET FIELD DATA --}
    {if:else}
        <p><strong>{field_title}: </strong>
        {if "{description}" != ""}<br /><small><em>{description}</em></small><br />{/if}
        {!-- QUERY TO GET FIELD DATA --}
            {exp:vmg_nested:query prefix="data_reg" sql="select fid_{field_id} from exp_forms_entries WHERE (form_id = '9' AND fid_371 = '{segment_4}' AND fentry_id = '{segment_5}') LIMIT 1"}
                {data_reg:fid_{field_id}}
            {/exp:vmg_nested:query}
        {!-- /QUERY TO GET FIELD DATA --}
        </p>
    {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

And the contents of the embedded "snippets/child-field-data" template are:

```
{!-- QUERY TO GET CHILD FIELD DATA --}
    {exp:query sql="select fid_{embed:field_id} from exp_forms_entries WHERE (form_id = '9' AND fid_371 = '{embed:segment_4}' {embed:fentry_query}) LIMIT 1"}

        <!-- query: select fid_{embed:field_id} from exp_forms_entries WHERE (form_id = '9' AND fid_371 = '{embed:segment_4}') LIMIT 1<br /> -->
        {!-- GET THE FIELD TYPE --}

        {exp:stash:set name="fielddatatype"}{exp:replace_plus find=":QUOTE:|;s" replace="" multiple="yes"}{exp:strexplode delimiter=":" string='{fid_{embed:field_id}}' index="4"}{/exp:replace_plus}{/exp:stash:set}
        {exp:stash:set name="nameorarea"}{exp:replace_plus find=":QUOTE:|;s" replace="" multiple="yes"}{exp:strexplode delimiter=":" string='{fid_{embed:field_id}}' index="6"}{/exp:replace_plus}{/exp:stash:set}
        {exp:stash:set name="lastnameorphone"}{exp:replace_plus find=":QUOTE:|;:RD:" replace="" multiple="yes"}{exp:strexplode delimiter=":" string='{fid_{embed:field_id}}' index="10"}{/exp:replace_plus}{/exp:stash:set}

        {if "{exp:stash:get name='fielddatatype'}" == "first_name"}
            {exp:stash:get name='nameorarea'} {exp:stash:get name='lastnameorphone'}
        {if:elseif "{exp:stash:get name='fielddatatype'}" == "area"}
            {if "{exp:stash:get name='nameorarea'}" !=""}({exp:stash:get name='nameorarea'}) {exp:stash:get name='lastnameorphone'}<br />{/if}
        {if:else}
            {fid_{embed:field_id}}
        {/if}

        <br />
    {/exp:query}
{!-- /QUERY TO GET CHILD FIELD DATA --}
```